# Chrome BookmarkTreeNode Has no 'children' property - are API docs out of date?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to traverse the bookmark tree synchronously but recursion through the tree like this:

```
function traverseBookmarks(bookmarkTreeNodes) {
for(var i=0;i<bookmarkTreeNodes.length;i++) {
    if(bookmarkTreeNodes[i].children) {
        traverseBookmarks(bookmarkTreeNodes[i].children);
    } 

   }
}
```

But when I print out the properties of `bookmarkTreeNodes[i]` using this:

```
function objToString(obj){
  var a = '';
  for(var p in obj){
    a += p + ' : ' + obj[p] + ' \n';
    }
  return a;
 }
```

I get this:

```
dateAdded : 1369804994102 
dateGroupModified : 1369805295054 
id : 2240 
index : 9 
parentId : 1 
title : Diet
```

There is no `children` property like the API says there should be. Without `children` there is no synchronous way to traverse the bookmark tree. Currently, I have to use the id of each folder node then use the asynchronous function `chrome.bookmarks.getChildren()` to retrieve the children which causes all sorts of other problems, such as subsequent code executing before async calls have finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's a bug in your code. To satisfy yourself that this is the case:

1. Either inspect your popup or open a page that your extension loads on, and switch the page context in the inspector to your extension.
2. Switch to the console.
3. Type `chrome.bookmarks.getTree(function(r){console.log(r);});`
4. Expand the object that gets logged. As long as you actually do have a hierarchy of bookmarks, you'll see objects with children, as promised.

You didn't say how you retrieved `bookmarkTreeNodes`, so it's not possible to tell from your question where the bug is. If you put a similar console.log at the top of your callback function and see different results, then you will have narrowed the bug to however you're getting `bookmarkTreeNodes`.

Comment: First of all thanks so much for your time! This was right in front of my face but I over complicated things. Much appreciated.